# duda con código en python

Tags: python, condiciones, else, spyder

espero qué se encuentren muy bien , el día de hoy tengo una pregunta acerca de un problema el cuál estoy intentando ponerle solución. Se trata de un juego en donde existe el "ataque" y la "defensa"; el problema es que no he podido realizarlo ya que tengo poca experiencia en este lenguaje de programación , por lo que pido un poco de paciencia si el código esta algo desordenado o mal escrito. A continuación escribiré el mismo:

import random as ra

```
        j1 = int(input("seleccionar ataque o defensa: "))
        if j1 == "ataque": 
            ataque1 = ra.randint(1,10)
        else: 
            j1 == "defensa":
             defensa1 = ra.randint(1,10)
                
        j2 = int(input("seleccionar ataque o defensa: "))
        if j2 == "ataque":
            ataque2 = ra.randint(1,10)
        else:
            j2 == "defensa":
                defensa2 = ra.randint(1,10)
                
        if j1 == "ataque" and j2 == "ataque":
            print(f"j1:{ataque1}")
            print(f"j2:{ataque2}")
            if ataque1 > ataque2:
                print("j1 gana")
            else:
                print("j2 gana")
                 
                
        if j1 == "defensa" and j2 == "defensa":
            print(f"j1:{defensa1} , j2:{defensa2"}
            print("no hay ataque, ambos jugadores eligieron defender")
            
            
        if j1 == "ataque" and j2 == "defensa":
            print(f"j1:{ataque1} , j2:{defensa2}")
            if ataque1 > defensa2:
                print("j1 gana")
            else:
                print("j2 gana")
                
                
        if j1 == "defensa" and j2 == "ataque":
            print(f"j1:{defensa1} , j2:{ataque2}")
            if defensa1 > ataque2:
                print("j1 gana")
            else:
                print(j2 gana)
```

El código me lanza error de sintaxis. Muchas gracias de antemano si desean ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

Tu código tiene varios errores de concepto y por eso no funciona.

1. En los `input` donde solicitas al usuario ingresar "ataque" o "defensa" tienes un `int`, eso convertiría lo que ingrese el usuario a un número entero por lo que si ingresa "ataque" o "defensa" como lo solicitas te envía el error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ataque'
```

La solución de esto es quitar el `int` ya que lo que necesitas es un `string` por lo que únicamente con `input` es suficiente.

2. Cuando pones los `else` para identificar si el usuario ingresó "ataque" o "defensa" lo haces de una foma que no existe en `python`:

```
else:
    j2 == "defensa":
```

Lo que necesitas es un `elif`:

```
elif j1 == "defensa":
```

3. En la línea de código `print(f"j1:{defensa1} , j2:{defensa2"}` estás cerrando las comillas antes de cerrar las llaves, debe ser así `print(f"j1:{defensa1} , j2:{defensa2}"`

Ejemplo aplicando las correcciones:

```
import random as ra

j1 = input("seleccionar ataque o defensa: ")
if j1 == "ataque": 
    ataque1 = ra.randint(1,10)
elif j1 == "defensa":
    defensa1 = ra.randint(1,10)

j2 = input("seleccionar ataque o defensa: ")
if j2 == "ataque":
    ataque2 = ra.randint(1,10)
elif j2 == "defensa":
    defensa2 = ra.randint(1,10)

if j1 == "ataque" and j2 == "ataque":
    print(f"j1:{ataque1}")
    print(f"j2:{ataque2}")
    if ataque1 > ataque2:
        print("j1 gana")
    else:
        print("j2 gana")


if j1 == "defensa" and j2 == "defensa":
    print(f"j1:{defensa1} , j2:{defensa2}")
    print("no hay ataque, ambos jugadores eligieron defender")


if j1 == "ataque" and j2 == "defensa":
    print(f"j1:{ataque1} , j2:{defensa2}")
    if ataque1 > defensa2:
        print("j1 gana")
    else:
        print("j2 gana")
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
seleccionar ataque o defensa:  ataque
seleccionar ataque o defensa:  defensa
j1:2 , j2:9
j2 gana
```

Comment: Mil gracias, me alegraste la noche.